# How to use function arguement to set column name

Tags: r

I have dataframe `df` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), y = 1:4)
```

And I have a function that finds the mean of `y` grouped by `x`:

```
generateVarMean <- function(df, x, y) {
  mean.df <- df %>%
    select(x, y) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(variable.mean = mean(y, na.rm = TRUE))
colnames(mean.df)[2] <- paste0("y", ".mean")
print(mean.df)
}
```

However, I want to the first argument of `paste0()` to reflect the actual function argument (i.e. so that it can be used for different dataframes).

Desired functionality:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), b = 1:4)
generateVarMean(df1, a, b)

  a b.mean
1 A    1.5
2 B    3.5
```

Any help getting pointed in the right direction very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add anything to the function. Just replace `paste0("y", ".mean")` with `paste0(deparse(substitute(y)), ".mean")`

So now the function and the output will be:

```
> generateVarMean <- function(df, x, y) {
   mean.df <- df %>%
     select(x, y) %>%
     group_by(x) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(variable.mean = mean(y, na.rm = TRUE))
 colnames(mean.df)[2] <- paste0(deparse(substitute(y)), ".mean")
 print(mean.df)
 }

> generateVarMean(df, a, b)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
       x b.mean
  <fctr>  <dbl>
1      A    1.5
2      B    3.5
```

Comment: Thanks @YannisVassiliadis. Learned how to use `deparse` and `substitute` in the process!

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the `quosure` from the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`)

```
generateVarMean <- function(df, x, y) {
   x <- enquo(x)
   y <- enquo(y)
   newName <- paste0(quo_name(y), ".mean")
   df %>%
       select(UQ(x), UQ(y)) %>%
       group_by(UQ(x)) %>%
       summarise(UQ(newName) := mean(UQ(y), na.rm = TRUE))            
 }

generateVarMean(df1, a, b)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#       a b.mean
#  <fctr>  <dbl>
#1      A    1.5
#2      B    3.5
```

We get the input arguments as `quosure` with `enquo`, convert the quosure to string with `quo_name` to create 'newName' string.  Then, evaluate the `quosure` inside `select/group_by/summarise` by unquoting (`UQ` or `!!`).  Note that in the new version, we can also assign the column names directly and using the assign operator (`:=`)