# How do I parameterize the column names in dplyr function calls

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose we have the following setup

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(10101)
id <- sample(3,20,replace = TRUE)
x <- sample(2,20,replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id,x)
```

How do I parameterize the following:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(id) %>% mutate(x.lag=lag(x,1,default=0))

cl <- "x"
cl.lag <- "x.lag.1"
```

my naive attempt does not seem to work:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(id) %>% mutate(cl.lag=lag(cl,1,default=0))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885497/how-to-use-function-arguement-to-set-column-name/43885596#43885596

Comment: @BenBolker thanks will check it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use function arguement to set column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885497/how-to-use-function-arguement-to-set-column-name)